# Setting "Allow all pipelines" when creating a service endpoint through DevOps API Create Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting to create a service endpoint through the Azure DevOps Rest API but cannot set the "Allow all pipelines to use this service connection" option.  I cannot find documentation on the json structure to accomplish this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#endpointauthorization

Current snippet for creating the connection:

```sh
$baseUri = "https://dev.azure.com/org/proj/";
$createEndpointUri = "$($baseUri)_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=5.0-preview.2";


$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("token:{0}" -f $devOpsPAT)))
$DevOpsHeaders = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)};

$AzureSubscriptionData = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
                            authorizationType = "AzureSubscription"
                            azureSubscriptionId = $SubscriptionId
                            azureSubscriptionName = $subscriptionName
                            clusterId = $clusterId
                            };
$Authorization = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                            parameters = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
                                azureEnvironment = "AzureCloud"
                                azureTenantId = "$tenantID"
                                };
                            scheme = "Kubernetes"
                            };

$ServiceEndpointBody = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
                            authorization =$Authorization
                            data = $AzureSubscriptionData
                            name = $serviceConnectionName
                            type = "kubernetes"
                            url = $k8sUrl
                            isReady = "true"
                            };

$jsonbody = $ServiceEndpointBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100


Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing -Uri $createEndpointUri -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $DevOpsHeaders -Body $jsonbody;
```

Comment: Show your attempts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can usually figure this stuff out by doing the operation in the Azure DevOps UI and inspecting the HTTP requests it makes using (for example) Chrome debugging tools.

In this case, I think you first need to create the service connection and then make a `PATCH` request to the `pipelinePermissions` endpoint, setting the `allPipelines.authorized` flag to true.

**URI**

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organisation}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/pipelinePermissions/endpoint/{endpointId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

**Patch Request Body**

```
{
    "allPipelines": {
        "authorized": true,
        "authorizedBy": null,
        "authorizedOn": null
    },
    "pipelines": null,
    "resource": {
        "id": "{endpointid}",
        "type": "endpoint"
    }
}
```

**Powershell**

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri "{uriasabove}" -Headers $headers -Body "{patchbodyasabove}" -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: Ah this is awesome.  I did use the tools to check what it was doing but was narrow sighted looking for the initial call to handle it.  This makes perfect sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above help, however I wanted to do all of this using bash script.

**patch.json**

```
{
    "allPipelines": {
        "authorized": true,
        "authorizedBy": null,
        "authorizedOn": null
    },
    "pipelines": null,
    "resource": {
        "id": "test-service-endpoint-id",
        "type": "endpoint"
    }
}
```

A simple **Bash Script** to achieve the same.

```
#!/bin/bash

token=test-token
organization_name=your-azuredevops-organisation
project=test-project
user=your-user-name
connection_name=test-connection

#Get Request for endpoint ID
connection_id=$(curl -X GET \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-u $user:$token \
https://dev.azure.com/$organization_name/$project/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints\?endpointNames\=$connection_name\&api-version\=5.1-preview.2 | jq '.value[].id' | tr -d "\"" )

#Creating newpatch.json with connection_id
cat patch.json | jq --arg conn_id "$connection_id" -r '.resource.id = $conn_id' > newpatch.json

curl --request PATCH \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-u $user:$token \
-d "@newpatch.json" https://dev.azure.com/$organization_name/$project/_apis/pipelines/pipelinePermissions/endpoint/$connection_id\?api-version\=5.1-preview.1
```